# Dual-boot with separate disk

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install ubuntu on separate ssd alongside windows 10.

Disk 1 with w10 is listed in ubuntu installer as sdb

Disk 0 on which i want to install ubuntu is listed as sda

So my question is, how should my partition table look like? :) Where do i need install grub, sda or sdb?

Until now i have only been using one drive for dual-boot.

Thanks in advance!

have a nice day :)

Comment: UEFI or BIOS hardware, and then is Windows in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? You will want Ubuntu in the same boot mode as Windows and how you boot install media is then how install will boot. Post this to see current partitions: `sudo parted -l`.  Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: hello @oldfred , windows is in UEFI mode, here is a screen with current partitions: https://imgur.com/a/AksepeP, id like to install ubuntu on adata su650

Comment: It looks like you used Windows to partition sda. You cannot install Linux into NTFS. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  May be best just to disconnect Windows drive, with physically or in UEFI settings and install Ubuntu using defaults if not familar with manual partitioning and Something Else install option. But you have to delete or shrink (using Windows) the existing NTFS partition.

Comment: @oldfred, so best option is just delete partition and leave it as unallocated, then unplugging windows ssd and install ubuntu on new ssd... when i plug back my w10 ssd, will grub recognize w10? :)

Comment: Grub will only recognize Windows if installed in same boot mode. And you have to run `sudo update-grub` to get grub to find it. And grub will not find Windows if Windows fast start up/hibernation is on as then it cannot read the NTFS partition.

Comment: @oldfred here is a summary: 1. I will make a free unallocated space on the new ssd 2. I will disable fast startup 3. I will disable w10 ssd in the bios 4. Ubuntu install with "erase disk and install ubuntu" option 5. I will enable w10 ssd 6. run grub update, find w10 and add it as entry. this should work, right? :)

Comment: Yes, as long as you install Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows. And how you boot install media, is how it installs. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  Then if still issues, as some brands of hardware or models may work better than others, post link to summary report from Boot-Repair and brand/model system.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be prompted during Ubuntu install to choose the drive to install Grub (it's the dropdown at the bottom of the 'something else' page). It doesn't matter which drive you put Grub on, as long as your BIOS boots the drive with Grub on it. Personally, I would put Grub on the new SSD.