# Move bootloader or remove efi partition in second drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, grub-efi

I'm new here so I apologize in advance if my question is not formally correct.

I have a dual boot system, on two different disks.
Windows was pre-installed on the first drive (500 Gb), then I installed ubuntu 20.04 on the second 1 Tb drive following the answer in this discussion [Dual Booting win 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on two separate physical ssds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds) (I find it very very useful and clear).
Both disks are SSD. The system is full uefi.
Since I wanted to completely isolate the two different operating systems I configured the second drive like this:

- 650 Mb Efi partition            (sdb1)
- 20 Gb Ext4 @ /                  (sdb2)
- 10 Gb Swap                      (sdb3)
- remaining free space @ /home    (sdb4)

During the ubuntu installation process I did not unplug the first drive (where Windows is) and I incredibly skipped (that's my fault, I know) the “workaround” steps to avoid the installation of ubuntu bootloader on the first drive (this situation is known as a bug as I read in the discussion linked before).
So, even if I chose the “sdb1” partition (just created) in the “Device for boot loader installation” menu, probably that bug occurred or simply my choice was ignored.
Now I have two questions, which represent for me two alternative ways to restore the situation:

1 – Can I move the ubuntu bootloader from the first drive, to Efi partition in the second drive? If yes, how can I do this? In this way I hope to isolate the two OS.

If not, the second question is:

2 – Since the ubuntu bootloader is now installed on the Efi partition of the first drive, can I delete the Efi partition of the second drive that I created during installation process? In fact I see that this partition is empty and unmounted, so basically unutilized.

Comment: I think both 1 and 2 are possible. However, I don't know. 1 seems particularly difficult. Either way you should backup everything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Facing the very same problem with Ubuntu 18.04, I followed PrakashS's answer while making sure the new EFI partition was mounted at `/boot/efi` before installing grub into it.

I first created a new fat32 partition with GParted on the Ubuntu disk, with the `boot` flag. (GParted automatically adds the `esp` flag when checking `boot`.)

The instructions below use `sdb1` for the new EFI parition to match the device name in your question.

1. Find the UUID of sdb1:
   `sudo blkid | grep /dev/sdb1`
2. In /etc/fstab, replace the UUID of the /boot/efi entry with that of sdb1:
   `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd> to save. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.
3. To enact the change, unmount Windows EFI from and mount Ubuntu EFI to /boot/efi:
   `sudo umount /boot/efi && sudo mount /boot/efi`
4. Confirm that it's sdb1 that is mounted at /boot/efi:
   `lsblk | grep /boot/efi`
5. Install grub on sdb (without part number):
   `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb`
6. Generate [initramfs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs) image:
   `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`
7. Generate grub2 config file:
   `sudo update-grub`
8. Reboot.
9. Confirm that it's still sdb1 that is mounted at /boot/efi:
   `lsblk | grep /boot/efi`

Comment: You're a life saver! Worked like a charm.

Comment: this was a clear and accurate answer. Tried it with ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Worked on Kubuntu 20.04 :)

Comment: A life saver! Worked on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 7):

Follow this procedure to move the boot loader:

1. Find the UUID of /dev/sdb1 using `sudo blkid` (copy it)
2. Change the UUID of boot/efi entry in /etc/fstab with that of
   sdb1
3. `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb`
4. `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`
5. `sudo update-grub`
6. Reboot

Check with `lsblk` whether /dev/sdb1 be mounted in
/boot/efi.

Comment: I find the system does not update correctly with new UUID until I reboot. Normally you can run `sudo mount -a` to remount fstab and it uses new mounts. You need to be sure it installs to sdb's ESP.

Comment: @mook765 So the soultion in my case could be:

1 – sudo umount /dev/sda2  
2 – sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /boot/efi
3 -  sudo grub-install
4 - reboot

These are the steps I have to follow? thanks

Comment: I confirmed this procedure just before writing answer with my spare installation, with ESP created in usb drive . (reverted back successfully by the same procedure)