# How to create EFI Partitions and add ubuntu to the list

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm installing ubuntu alongside windows 10 with UEFI. I'm installing ubuntu in a different drive (nvme0np->win10, sda->ubuntu) using the custom install option (the one that lets you create partitions manually).

The thing is, I forgot to create EFI partition in the second drive (sda); so the ubuntu is using the same EFI partition that already exists on the first drive.

Drive0 = nvme0np -> efi partition & win10

Drive1 = sda -> ubuntu

[image: system partition]

The installation kinda works but not really.

Case 1: Powering on laptop -> stuck into Grub CLI

Case 2: Powering on laptop -> pressing F2 to display bios boot options -> select ubuntu -> successfully boot into Grub menu (both ubuntu & win10 is detected)

My boot priority setting is already correct (1. ubuntu, 2. windows boot manager) so I don't see any problem here.
In case 1, I tried to type "ls" and it only shows partitions from the nvme0np (win10 drive). I don't know why this happens, maybe my laptop doesn't power up the 2 drives at the same time????

I want to try creating a different EFI partition in the second drive & add the ubuntu boot entry to that partition but I can't find any tutorial on how to do that. If anyone knows how to fix my problem, please give the steps or reference to a tutorial. Thanks...

Comment: It seems to me you don't have to create a new ESP on sda. Since the system boots normally from grub2 located in nvme0np's ESP and linked to Ubuntu (case 2), you just need to set the default boot item to `\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI` via UEFI bios or via `efibootmgr`, although why case 1 (Grub CLI) happens remains unclear.

Comment: Only one ESP per system is needed and recommended.

Comment: I always put an ESP on every drive even smaller flash drives and use gpt partitioning. You can have one per drive, but normally Ubuntu installs grub to first drive's ESP. UEFI defines what is first drive when you have multiple drives, but not usually obvious. Old but still valid bug with some work arounds when installing: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator Good link in your answer on reinstall of grub once installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move bootloader or remove efi partition in second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250199/move-bootloader-or-remove-efi-partition-in-second-drive)

Answer (score -1):

Problem 1 (grub CLI) was solved by disabling fast boot in the BIOS setting.
Problem 2 (creating a new EFI partition) was solved by following this answer [Move bootloader or remove efi partition in second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250199/move-bootloader-or-remove-efi-partition-in-second-drive)