# Create a new bootloader on another disk for an already installed Ubuntu

Tags: windows, bootloader

So here is my scenario: I have a ssd with Ubuntu installed (lets call it SSD_A) which one I installed its bootloader on another ssd with Windows (lets call this windows ssd as SSD_B).

But now I have to get my SSD_A with Ubuntu installed without a bootloader, and switch to another PC that has another ssd with Windows already installed too (lets call this SSD_C). Then now what I have to do is to install a new bootloader for my already installed Ubuntu on this new SSD_C with Windows to load Ubuntu which is located in SSD_A.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use Boot Repair - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair - by booting a Ubuntu live session and following the instructions in the "2nd option", after physically attaching the drive. Do not change anything else in UEFI.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Just be sure to boot live installer in correct mode as Boot-Repair will repair in that mode. If BIOS often better to have grub boot loader in MBR of Ubuntu drive. And if UEFI, you can add an ESP to Ubuntu drive & reinstall grub using that. You do have to update fstab first with correct UUID for ESP. https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250199/move-bootloader-or-remove-efi-partition-in-second-drive/1296430#1296430