# dual boot with windows- ubuntu cannot run without windows

Tags: dual-boot

I have two SSD.

```
 1. Micron Crucial MX500 250G      (install Ubuntu20.04)
 2. Intel  670P 512G SSD PCIe NVMe (install windows10)
```

Sometimes I need to carry my ubuntu (SSD1) to switch between different computers. However, my ubuntu cannot run without windows. Is there any way to fix it except recomputer?

Last year I was a rookie with no experience with linux system. Below are my installation steps.

```
1. Install windwos on SSD 2
2. After installing ubuntu on another computer mount the SSD 1 to my computer
```

But at the time I didn't know I needed to disable secure boot result in ubuntu wouldn't boot properly.

Finally, I install ubuntu on my computer and choose

```
**install ubuntu along with windows boot manager**
```

[Windows Disk Management pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGSJG.png)

[EFI Folder pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFb6E.png)

Comment: The ESP is where your computer boots from. If you remove the drive containing it then nothing boots, obviously.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying my question. But the efi is on the SSD1 which is the SSD I install ubuntu.
I try to this method but  I failed
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250199/move-bootloader-or-remove-efi-partition-in-second-drive

Comment: You actually have 2... You may, in the absence of Disk1, to open UEFI settings > Boot and try to select "Windows". It may or may not work.

Comment: I tried it before, windows can boot independently. Just need to change the boot order(set SSD2 to top priority).

Comment: You need to install Grub in the other ESP as well. You can try removing or simply disabling "Disk2" and then use Boot Repair from a live session: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks! After I try it, I will let you know.

Comment: @ChanganAuto It work! thanks