# error: file ./boot' not found, after installing Ubuntu 20.04 on an external SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 20.04

I've decided recently to install Ubuntu on an external SSD. I want to use it as a "work OS" that I could plug anywhere.

After some research, I found that with usb 3.0 throughput, there are no problems running an OS from an external drive.

I have also found [this recent guide to install a portable ubuntu on an external drive](https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/02/28/how-create-truly-portable-ubuntu-installation-external-usb-hdd-or-ssd).

I've managed to install ubuntu 20.04 (rather than 19.10 in his tutorial) which works quite well but is bound to the computer where I installed it.

So in order to manage this issue, while being on a "Try ubuntu" thumb drive session, they describe how to mount the external device with the fresh ubuntu install, to change the mount points in `/mnt/etc/fstab` and to chroot in it for installing grub on the efs partition. (If you wanna check, part **E** of his guide)

The problem is that I have followed each steps carefully 3 times, but when I boot on this device with another computer that only has a W10 on it, my screen freezes with this error: `error: file ./boot' not found.` I have checked on my SSD and the `/boot/*` directory does exist.

[The message on my screen when I boot on the external SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nusv.png)

I have tried different arguments with `grub-install` but nothing seems to change.

Do you have any ideas as to why another computer couldn't find the grub installation on my SSD?

Comment: Does the first computer that has Windows 10 only, you used to create the Ubuntu USB boot properly? Or does it boot to grub if the USB is unplugged?

Comment: @user68186 ok I should have said that. The PC I used to install Ubuntu on my external SSD was a PC that already had a dual-boot w10 - ubuntu 20.04. I used a bootable key for the installation. The ubuntu 20.04 from external SSD boot normaly when I use it on this PC. But I got the error when I try with another PC than the one I used to install it.

Comment: It sounds like you may have copied the EFI files of the wrong installed version of Ubuntu in the USB. I can't be sure.

Comment: Try to start over. Use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds/1130381#1130381) as model. Except you have an external drive and an internal drive.

Comment: The tutorial you followed does not have a BIOS boot partition. If you want it to boot in either BIOS or UEFI mode, see any of the methods here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Comment: @user68186 I deleted my old ubuntu partitions (so now I just have a pc with W10 installed) then I start your tutorial. I could boot ubuntu/W10 with grub on this computer, but if I try to plug my ssd with ubuntu fresh install on my desktop pc, I can't choose it anymore as a boot option.

Comment: This is a different problem. Please search the site for similar questions. If you don't find an answer, please ask a new question.

Comment: Update: It finaly works on any device, I don't really know why. It's most likely because I updated Ubuntu and grub to the last version. Thanks again @user68186.
NB : I had another problem with grub which doesn't want to launch ubuntu. It was due to a bios setting which allow to boot only on a windows system EFI that I had to change.