# Failed to install Ubuntu on external SSD in dual boot with Windows 10 over an AMD Ryzen processor

Tags: dual-boot, external-hdd, grub-efi, amd-ryzen

I have an Asus AMD Ryzen7 equipped with Windows10 installed on `/dev/nvme0n1` .
I would like to install Ubuntu 20.04 on an external SSD `/dev/sda` .

Using an Ubuntu Live USB `/dev/sdb`, I tried several times, in vain, to install Ubuntu on the external SSD.
The install process seemed to go fine and smooth, however, at the last stage after installation complete and before rebooting, I got the following message:

```
Executing grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 failed. This is a fatal error
```

Please note that:

- The disk `/dev/nvme0n1` has an EFI partition over `/dev/nvme0n1p1` containing the Windows Boot Manager.
- Over the external SSD disk `/dev/sda`,
  I defined another EFI partition over `/dev/sda1`. This EFI partition will allow the external SSD to become Ubuntu bootable independantly of the current PC.
  I defined an ext4 partition `/dev/sda2` mount to `/`. This partition will hold the entire Ubuntu system.
  I defined a FAT32 partition `/dev/sda3`. This partition will be shareable partition between Ubuntu and Windows10.

I would like that the Ubuntu installation (grub) add an Ubuntu boot entry inside the Windows Boot Manager.
So during the installation, I chose `/dev/nvme0n1p1` as a "*device for boot loader installation*".
And I got the error message :

```
Executing grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 failed. This is a fatal error
Please find the boot-repair report at the following link
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gG6ykKD9nR/
```

Moreover, I made a 2nd try by choosing `/dev/sda1` as a "*device for boot loader installation*".
I got a similar error message :

```
Executing grub-install /dev/sda1 failed. This is a fatal error.
```

I also checked that the "fast boot" and "secure boot" are disabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try choosing the device instead of a partition.  See lunchpad bug 1396379, where sda will be used whichever device you choose, which seems to be what you want anyway.

Comment: Actually I tried both, but the result still failing.

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds).