# If i Erase disk and Install Ubuntu where ubuntu will be installed, in SSD or HDD?

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, windows

I want to install Ubuntu and remove windows, but im just confuse where Ubuntu will be installed in ssd or hdd ?

Comment: Wherever you tell it to. In the installer, it will tell you which disk it will install to. If you want to pick where partitions and stuff go, you can do it manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu on a separate SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308331/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-separate-ssd)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment by @cocomac, the Ubuntu installer will ask you where you want Ubuntu to be installed. It will give several out of the box options like installing Ubuntu over Windows and installing alongside Windows, and it will also allow you to manually reconfigure disks and partitions then select which partition to install Ubuntu in.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide on which drive you want to install Ubuntu during the installation. In the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" dialog, you see the "Select drive:" pulldown. It allows you to select the drive.

[image]