# upgrade from ubuntu 18 to 20 on dual disk system

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, uefi

I am going to install ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a second drive following the instructions in
[Dual Booting win 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on two separate physical ssds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds)
including changing the UEFI partition on disk a so that it is not overwritten by the installation of ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
If, and when,I upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 LTS, do I have to take the same precautions about protecting the UEFI partition on disk a

Comment: Upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 from within the installed Ubuntu is different from erasing 18.04 and installing 20.04. If you upgrade it will not affect the ESP. So, no extra precaution is needed.

Comment: Why would you install Ubuntu 18.04 now, and not 20.04?

Comment: My apologies for my lack of good notation, I want to install 18.04, with the possibility of upgrading to 20.04 or 22.04 (when available)
Thank you, user68186, for understanding my question, and providing the answer to my question.
@Artur, I am a very slow learner.  I have a USB key with Ubuntu 18.04 on it, Ubuntu 18.04 on the machine in my office, and very specific instructions for installing 18.04 for boot from a second disk when windows 10 is on the first disk. I hope to advance to 20.04 or 22.04 in the future.