# GRUB Issue on UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, 20.04, uefi

My Laptop: asus rog gl503ge. Dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows, where my ubuntu is **installed in D drive**.

Story:
Recently, I have tried to install Ubuntu into a pendrive so I followed this https://www.tecmint.com/install-linux-os-on-usb-drive/ . **But I didn't create a partition in the pendrive**. After the installation completed, I removed the live usb but didn't remove the main usb where I installed the ubuntu. Now I rebooted it and when the GRUB showed up I found my dual boot and as well as the ubuntu in pendrive.

When I tried to reboot without the pendrive I ended with the grub terminal so I tried this method https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/ and this worked fine for me but, my windows logo(in my case it's rog logo) went missing while booting. So, I tried to update my BIOS and thought it would work fine but, the another issue appeared.

Issue:
As said above, I followed the itsfoss method for ubuntu and repaired my GRUB. **Unknowingly when I installed my ubuntu as a dualboot I didn't create a efi partition** and when I used the boot-repair tool I accidentally selected efi partition as windows efi partition. It was in advanced options and I didn't see that :( . So, My issue is whenever I tried to reboot again after repairing the GRUB using boot-repair tool also, I end up with GRUB menu only. **But, if I reboot again I end up with GRUB terminal.** And to my surprise I went to BIOS setting while booting again thinking of checking any error happened there and I found none so, I rebooted without any changes in the BIOS to my surprise I found GRUB menu when my laptop rebooted. But, when I rebooted without going into the BIOS I am getting stuck with GRUB terminal

**Main Issue:when I rebooted without going into the BIOS I am getting stuck with GRUB terminal but when I go to bios and do nothing and boot the laptop I am getting GRUB menu.**

**Boot priority in BIOS: 1.Ubuntu 2.Windows**

Comment: "D drive" is Windows terminology. It isn't applicable anywhere or to anything else than Windows. Before anything else make sure "Ubuntu" is selected in UEFI ("BIOS") settings > Boot.

Comment: Ubuntu is first in the boot priority for my laptop though :D

My issue was that even after using boot-repair I am stuck with the GRUB terminal.

Comment: You have to have an ESP - efi system partition FAT32 on the external drive. And then reinstall grub to that. And remove grub from internal drive and set default boot order to external drive and if not found boot Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Comment: I understand oldfred but, my issue was with my Internal disk GRUB (Where I installed dual boot). I removed the USB completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used boot-repair package to fix this. The grub always goes to the latest installed ubuntu. Put the usb in. Boot. install boot-repair. ---
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/11/install-boot-repair-ppa-fix-boot-problems/  - It may be possible to boot the Ubuntu from a bios menu
as ChanganAuto says. But the grub might not update anymore.

Comment: Exactly, I too tried this but what happened is, it worked only for the first time and whenever I reboot the laptop or shutdown and start it again I end up with the grub terminal.

In steps I mean,
1.Use boot-repair to repair GRUB
2.Now, Reboot with removing the live usb, now the GRUB menu appears and it's tottaly fine now.
3.When I reboot again I end up with GRUB terminal. so, I went to BIOS by entering **reboot** in the GRUB terminal.
4.I do nothing in my BIOS Settings. So, i enter escape to exit and boot the laptop.
5.Boom GRUB menu appears from no nowhere.

Comment: So are you saying the boot-repair fixed your problem?

Comment: If you want to make a usb install of ubuntu, remove the hard drive from laptop first, I think that will do it. The latest grub will have no idea of another grub.

Comment: No, using boot-repair didn't solved it. It solved it temporarily i.e, after rebooting my laptop more than a time I am stuck with the GRUB terminal again.

Comment: The only way I would go is backup all the data, say on external USB hard drive, boot on a usb, use gparted or partitionmanager to shrink your drive to give you 14Gb of free space, install a minimum ubuntu on the free space, this will give the grub control to this new ubuntu.

Comment: Did you try to boot the laptop from a bios menu, on my PC I have the option to boot from any drive, of course you could leave the usb stick in, and choose the option to boot into your laptop, if you did a update-grub on the usb.

Comment: yes, keith thinking to remove my dual boot and reinstall. I do nothing in the bios and exit the bios and I get the GRUB menu. So, I backed up the data successfully.