# Ubuntu install on ssd

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

Hello I wanted to install Linux on a fresh new ssd without having to uninstall Windows. I currently have a ssd nvme for Windows OS, one 2tb hdd for my files and I just bought a 2.5 ssd(sata 3) to install Ubuntu there. I'm  using a usb flash disc for the install. All good untill I check the option of parallel OS. On the next step when I'm asked to choose disc for Linux it only shows my HDD . None of my ssds appear. I'm not familiar with partitions (ntf ex4 ) and that other stuff I find online. Also I found that I have to change my my data connection from RAID to AHCI. When i checked bios AHCI option was already chosen. Since I'm just now trying to understand partitions I would like if someone could help my solve this issue. Thanks a a lot!

Comment: There is nothing about "parallel OS" pertaining to an Ubuntu installation. Are you certain that your details are accurate? It's essential that you use the exact text so we know what you're talking about.  The new disk needs to be formatted and needs enough **unpartitioned free space** to install Ubuntu. You can do this with the "Disks" application when you "Try Ubuntu" booting your installation media. Do not create any partitions for Ubuntu. This will complicate installation. The installer will create the file systems and partitions it needs.

Comment: There is a guided "Install alongside Windows" option that will only be available if 1) You have enough unpartitioned free space for Ubuntu and 2) You boot the installation media using the same mode as your current Windows installation (typically UEFI)

Comment: @Nmath thanks for the quick answer. My English are pretty bad with this issues I will try what you said and will update the issue thanks

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install. Most are now UEFI. With multiple drives, you really need to partition in advance to have an ESP - efi system partition on new drive. Otherwise only if you unplug or disable all other drives will Ubiquity installer put ESP on Ubuntu drive. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions use swap file so swap partition optional:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware?

Comment: @oldfred if Windows is already installed UEFI then there is already a ESP

Comment: Ubuntu uses an existing ESP on first drive. If you want drive totally independent, you need an ESP on that drive. More important if external drive of any type. If drive will always be used as internal drive then using existing ESP works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reposne guys. What worked for me was to unplug my NVMe ssd and my HDD and only leave the new SSD for the Ubuntu. It works perfectly now