# Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows Partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I am trying to install **Ubuntu** with **Windows 11** on my device to make it as multi bootable OS.

I chose the installation Type:

- **Install Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows Bootable Manager**

I have 2 Drives on my Windows OS:

- Drive **C** which **Win 11** installed on it.
- the other drive is **D** which is empty.

I want to install Ubuntu Desktop on drive **D** alongside windows. I have selected drive **D** for installation.

The question here what does **Ubuntu** partition on the right side mean and **Files** on the left side represent. Also what the divide slider do between each partition?

[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me if "Drive D" is a physical drive or a partition in the same disk as "Drive C". If D is physical disk This question is a possible duplicate of [Dual Booting win 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on two separate physical ssds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds)

Comment: Best to always use Windows tools to shrink the Windows NTFS partition and reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk which it requires after any resize. Make sure Windows fast startup and bitlocker are off. Then you can install Ubuntu into the unallocated space, so not choose any full drive installs as in Linux that is the entire device, all partitions. Be sure to boot in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: @oldfred thanks for the tips. do you know what Files partition mean on the attached image?

Comment: I name/label partitions, so any I do not mount and then are automounted use that label. Do you have a NTFS partition sda3 with label "Files"? You can see labels of all partitions: `lsblk -f`

Answer (score 3):

In the screenshot you posted, the infographic represents the proposed layout of the disk after installation. The Ubuntu portion tells you where Ubuntu will be installed. The slider allows you to choose how to divide the finite space between the multiple partitions.

There is no such thing as "Drive D" in Ubuntu. These drive letter associations are labels that only exist within the Windows environment and don't pertain to Ubuntu.

You must have enough **unpartitioned free space** to get the guided installation options to install alongside Windows. You also need to boot the USB as UEFI *(unless Windows is installed in compatibility/MBR mode which is very uncommon)*.

If Windows identifies the space with a drive letter, then the space might already be partitioned. If so, then **you may need to delete the partition in order for the Ubuntu installer to recognize it as available for installation alongside Windows.** It must be **unpartitioned free space**.

If you need step-by-step instructions, or if you need help understanding what to do on each screen, follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). Please be aware that the instructions are more complex when setting up dual boot configuration. Please read the entire tutorial, including relevant links **before** you start following along.

Comment: So what does the files on left side represent ?! is it partition on windows?

Comment: I read the official documentation on Ubuntu but Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Bootable Manager part seems confusing to me.

Comment: It's probably your Windows partition, but don't guess. There should be enough information for you to recognize what disk this is. For example, the whole disk is 80 GB. If you don't know, find out.  And don't forget to back up. If you make a mistake and overwrite Windows and you have important data without backups, you'll have a very bad day. As far as your other question, can you be more specific about what you're confused about?

Comment: Also look at the labels. Ubuntu disk naming schemes are in the format `sdx#` where `x` is a physical disk represented by a letter starting with `a` and `#` is a partition on that disk starting with `1`. So `sda3` is the third partition on the first disk Ubuntu found when scanning for disks

Comment: Thanks for the info very helpful!