# Do I still need to turn off some flags while installing Ubuntu with Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I remember that when I was installing older versions of Ubuntu I needed to turn off some flags in Windows efi partition just so Ubuntu doesn't install in that partition. Right now it's a version 22 and I have a clean Windows Disk and clean disk for ubuntu. Do I still have to do some manipulations or I can just install Ubuntu and it will be okay?

Comment: Turning off EFI flag in the EFI System Partition (ESP) is only required in Ubuntu 22.04 if you want to install Ubuntu in a second physical disk and want to create a separate ESP for Ubuntu in the second physical disk. A single ESP in the Windows physical disk is the default and works fine. Note: this is only if you have two separate **physical disks** and want to install in a different disk. If you have C: drive and D: drive both in the same physical disk, (and you want to replace D: with Ubuntu) this does not apply.

Comment: See [Dual Booting win 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on two separate physical ssds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds) for more details. This applies to Ubuntu 22.04 as well.